# Integrating OAuth (GitHub) with ELK Stack Using Apache & Reverse Proxy: Configuration and Authentication Issues

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, certificate, logstash, kibana

I am attempting to integrate OAuth (specifically GitHub) with the ELK Stack and am using Apache and reverse proxy for authentication. From what I've understood, authentication typically requires the premium package, but I am working with the basic ELK stack. I've come across a method that allows this integration using Apache and reverse proxy, but I'm a bit stuck on properly configuring my xpack.

I've cloned the repo from here: https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk

Here are the xpack rules I added:

```
# xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
# xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.type: PKCS12
# xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
# xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-stack-ca.p12
# xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-stack-ca.p12
# xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.type: PKCS12
```

However, I am facing a few problems:

How do I generate the test.p12 certificate for the keystore and truststore? I am unclear about the process.
Once the xpack configuration is set, what would be the next steps to connect it to OAuth? And how many more steps are remaining?
I would appreciate any guidance or resources on this topic.